# Динамическое добавление item-ов в ListView

Tags: android, listview

Нужно при нажатии на кнопку добавлять новый item в ListView.
Но ничего не происходит. Пункт не добавляется.

Шаблон item-а:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:maxLength="7"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textNoSuggestions"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/krestic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_remove" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Код реализации:

```
ListView lv_contentFragment;
ArrayList<LinearLayout> mas_items = null;                                    
ArrayAdapter<LinearLayout> lv_adapter = null;

public void onClick(View v) {
    mas_items = new ArrayList<>();
    lv_adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.item_price_name, mas_items);
    mas_items.add((LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_price_name, null));
    lv_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте поменять местами инициализации `lv_adapter = new....` с `mas_items.add(....`

Comment: DevOma, не помогло

Comment: А где код, который добавляет адаптер к ListView ?

Answer (score 0):

При каждом клике создается новый массив:

```
mas_items = new ArrayList<>();
```

И добавляется один элемент. Массив нужно создать один раз, вынести в конструктор activity, например, или лениво проинициализировать прямо при объявлении.

UPD: и вообще, в массиве с данными должны храниться данные, а не лейауты.

Comment: Более того, при каждом клике создается новый адаптер!